# Reduce binary number beyond hexadecimal format in C

Tags: c, string

i'm working with a program which generates millions of binary strings, and i need to keep them in a binary tree on memory, but the strings are 2048 chars long (1001011....101). So far i have converted them to hexadecimal format and could get 512 chars strings achieving to store only 1/4 of the original string size, but its still too large to keep all of them on memory. So i was wondering if there is a way to reduce a binary string even more warrantying the uniqueness of every converted string. Thanks!

Comment: Why store strings at all? Just store 2048 bits as 2048 bits (i.e., 256 `uint8_t`s or 64 `uint32_t`s.)  Strings are for humans.  Computers use numbers.

Comment: but i have the binary as a string, so what would be the way to convert that 2048 chars string into a uint8_t or uint32_t?

Comment: If that's not obvious, you really shouldn't be programming in C. Let's say your strings were only 32 chars. Then you'd just: `uint32_t val = 0; for (i = 0; i < 32; i += 1) { val <<= 1; val |= (str[i] & 1); }`. For 2048 chars, just do this 64 times.

Comment: a) Allocate a 256-byte array. Every eight digits of your string gets converted to a byte and then appended to the array. b) there are free "bignum" libraries for C that can do this for you; you should be using them already. c) why do they have to be stored in memory? Why not on disk?

Comment: Several of the answers assume that a byte is exactly 8 bits (`CHAR_BIT==8`). That's almost certainly a safe assumption, but it's worth either making it explicit or using `CHAR_BIT` rather than `8` in the code. (Actually, since you'll probably never be able to test the code on a system with `CHAR_BIT > 8`, you might consider something like `#if CHAR_BIT > 8` ... `#error "Only supported on systems with 8-bit bytes"` ... `#endif`.

Comment: a hex byte is 8 bits, so reduce the overall length by 8:1  by changing each input char to a single bit in a hex byte.

Answer (score 2):

Do not store the strings as strings, store them as raw numbers. In a sense, this is equivalent to a "Base-256" encoding, so to speak. Of course in reality this is simply a large unsigned integer composed of bytes. You can do your comparisons on these numbers in the usual way.

When you need to print your binary string, format the number as needed. In other words, the particular radix should enter the picture only when you need to treat values as strings with a particular radix.

Comment: this generalized/vague answer will not help the OP with the problem

Comment: @user3629249 It is neither vague nor generalized: recommendation to "store numbers as numbers, not as strings" is as specific as it gets.

Answer (score 1):

You can use char data type to store 8 bits in a char i.e. 256 char array for a single string.

To compress more it is necessary to monitor at your data pattern. According to the pattern you can choose a compression algorithm for compress the data.

Comment: using char to store numbers is old-school. If nothing else, the signed/unsigned property of char is not defined. Instead, #include <stdint.h> and use uint8_t

Comment: Yes, then use a compression algorithm. @Luis

Comment: i have read that a compression method wouldn't be ok for binaries (since a pattern is hard to be found), and still hexadecimal representation its better.

Answer (score 0):

A string of digits 1 and 0 of a length 8: `"01010110"`, can be stored in a single character( `unsigned char`).

2048 characters of either 1 or 0 / bits in a char = 256

From there on, you have to use compression.

You can convert it manually with bit operators or using sprintf()

For example:

```
unsigned char n = 0 ;
char* s = "11010110" ;

for( size_t i = 0 ; i < 8 ; i++ )
{
    if( s[i] == '1' )
    {
        n |= 1u << ( 7 - i ) ;
    }
}
```

And so on until you have any input left.

Comment: If you're storing raw binary in an array of `unsigned char`, it's not a string (which is by definition terminated by a zero byte). Just don't use any string functions on it. Of course you'll need to use some other method to keep track of the length (the question seems to imply that that's a compile-time constant).

Answer (score 0):

You should be using one of the free bignum libraries, such as [GNU MP](https://gmplib.org/). There are other, less legally-encumbered libraries as well. I'm surprised you're not using one already -- how are you generating your 2048-bit strings in the first place?

Second, why store them in memory? Why not on disk? Or use a database engine even?

Is this a homework assignment?

Comment: Its about a research im doing and i need to get it as quick as possible, thats the memory reason. I have 20GB RAM on the PC but i need to optimize the tree load on the memory. I will check the library, thanks!

Comment: So basically, you have a bunch of 2048-bit numbers and you want to know if they're in memory or not? Is there more data attached to the numbers, or is it just the numbers themselves? If so, a heap is almost certainly the way to go (I think).

Comment: To expand: a heap is a binary tree which follows certain rules about how it's filled out. A binary tree is an ideal way to represent a set of binary numbers (which is what you have). If your tree is a heap, there is an extremely efficient way to store it in a simple array. Unfortunately, it's been so long since I worked with heaps that I've forgotten the details, but this is an area you should look into.

Comment: What i really need is to represent a binary number stored in a char array. For example: char *array = "1101010101...."; I have to store the result in memory but a [2048] string its way too big for this purpose. So what im looking for is a smaller representation of my binary string beyond hexadecimal or 64-base to store that on a tree.

Answer (score 0):

Well i finally got with a nice propose that works just fine.

```
double bin2double(unsigned char *binstr, size_t len)
{
    double ret = 0;
    size_t cur;
    for(cur = 0; cur < len; cur++)
      {
        ret *= 1.001;
        ret += binstr[cur] - 48;
      }
    return ret;
}
```

With this i get a different double value for every different binary string binstr of size len, which i can easily load on my tree. Thanks to everyone.

Answer (score -1):

If you really need to treat the data as a string rather than a binary byte array, you can use [Base64 encoding](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Base64) to turn every 24 bits into 4 characters. This is an improvement over hexadecimal, which converts 24 bits into 6 characters. It's still not as good as a pure binary representation, with 24 bits turning into 3 8-bit characters.

The danger of a binary array is that you can't use string functions with it, as any sequence of 8 0-bits will be interpreted as the end of the string. You need to use functions such as `memcmp` which take an explicit number of bytes.

Comment: "The danger of a binary array is that you can't use string functions with it ..." -- How is that a danger? It's just a matter of being aware of what kind of data you're working with.

Comment: @KeithThompson I was just pointing out a trap that should be obvious but might not be. I can't assume anybody asking this question would be aware of the subtleties.